# Java simple bitwise operation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operations

We are given integer n, value v (v=0 or 1) and a position p. Write a sequence of operators that modifies n to hold the value v at the position p from the binary representation of n. Example:

- n = 5 (00000101), p=3, v=1 -> 13 (00001101)
- n = 5 (00000101), p=2, v=0 ->  1 (00000001)

This is my code:

```
int n1 = 35;
int p1 = 3;
int v = 1;
n1 = n1 + (v << p1);
System.out.println(n1);
```

It works when the v=1 but when the v=0 it doesn't.

Comment: Using the sum, if v=0, you are adding 0 (shifting does not change the fact that it is 0), so the value doesn't change. You might want to look for a different operation there. Probably a bit operation.

Comment: I'm not answering with the solution because this definitely looks like an assignment, you should be able to achieve that by yourself.

Comment: @bracco23 It does look like an assignment, and for such things I typically offer approaches without code.  Hope you don't mind.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "set" the index to a value, you need one of two operations

```
'and' will set 0 values at an index to 0, but won't work for 1 values
'or' will set 1 values at an index to 1, but won't work for 0 values
```

Now all you need to do is put the right number at the right index.  This can be done by shifting 1.

```
'<<' moves the 1 a number of places
```

for example

```
'1 << 3' shifts the 1 three places, resulting in '00001000'
```

remember, we need a zero for some of the operations, to get a zero in that place, you need to invert the bits

```
'not' or '~' flips all the bits in a number

~00001000 yeilds 11110111
```

Now we can have a 1 or a 0 in the index we wish, and only need to use an if statement to pick the right one based on the desired operation and apply the corresponding `and` or `or` operation to set the bit we want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think that is going to work, but how to print the result properly on the console?

```
    // Swapping i and j: i ^= j, j ^= i, i ^= j;
    // Getting the pth byte: (n >> p) & 1
    // Setting the pth byte to v: (v == 0) ? (n & ~(1 << p)) : (n | 1 << p)
    static int Exchange(int n, int i, int j)
    {
        n = ((n >> i) & 1 ^ (n >> j) & 1) == 0 ? (n & ~(1 << j)) : (n | 1 << j);
        n = ((n >> i) & 1 ^ (n >> j) & 1) == 0 ? (n & ~(1 << i)) : (n | 1 << i);
        n = ((n >> i) & 1 ^ (n >> j) & 1) == 0 ? (n & ~(1 << j)) : (n | 1 << j);

        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
        {
            int n = 56, p = 3, q = 24, k = 3;

            while (k-- != 0) n = Exchange(n, p++, q++);
        }
```